# Adding an image to the Qt toolbar area

Tags: c++, qt, toolbar

I was making a Qt application and after placing my actions, still a lot of empty space is left in the toolbar.
I was trying to add an image to the right side of icons, and was told it is possible using QLabel object and placing an image using QPixmap. But I've not been able to add the QLabel to the toolbar.

Comment: What happens when you use the [`addWidget(QWidget*)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#addWidget) method with your `QLabel` from the toolbar?

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know which method your're talking about. Maybe elaborate a bit on how to do it.

Comment: The previous comment contains a link to that method. You create the label with the pixmap and then call something like `this->ui.toolbar->addWidget(my_qlabel_with_pixmap)`

Comment: It's showing an error saying `'QAction *QToolBar::addWidget(QWidget *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'QLabel' to 'QWidget *`

Comment: You have to provide a pointer and not the object itself, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`QToolbar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html) already contains all the functionality you need. Simply user the [`addWidget(QWidget*`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#addWidget) method and supply a **pointer** to the widget (your label).

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel();
label->setPixmap(QPixmap("..."));

this->ui.toolbar->setWidget(label);
```